# we are trying to create a reports with all sobjects even though it has relationship or not

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, wrapper-class

We are trying show reports data in a table similar to Salesforce we are unable to show data like
Salesforce. please find below the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Do you have private contacts without accounts?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain? Are you trying to build a report in an lightning component? Would a listview not give you that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see accounts both with and without contacts in a report I think that you need to build an custom report type.
A: With primary object: Account
B: Relationship: Contact (select "A" records may or may not have related "B" records.
[image]

If you are trying to build a lightning component based on report data you might find this useful:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/transforming-analytics-api-data-salesforce1-lightning-components.html

Comment: if we had only relationship with the object then only we can able to create an report type